# Upload file and form data using AngularJS and Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file with some other form data from AngularJS using $http to Spring MVC controller. I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required request part 'file' is not present
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Here is the `AngularJS` code sending the `post` request:

```
service.create = function(id, photo) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', photo.name);
            formData.append('file', photo.file);
            formData.append('story', photo.story);
            if (!photo.url) {
                photo.url = null;
            }
            formData.append('url', photo.url);
            return $http(
                    {
                        method : 'POST',
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        transformResponse: angular.identity,
                        url : BASE_URL + authService.getToken().id
                                + '/resource/' + id + '/photo/',
                        data : formData,
                        headers : {
                            'Content-Type' : undefined
                        }
                    }).then(function(res) {
                return res;
            });
        };
```

And here is my `Spring MVC controller` method receiving the request:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(path = "user/{uid}/resource/{lid}/photo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Photo create(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable int uid, @PathVariable int lid,
        @RequestParam MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String url, @RequestParam String story) {
    return photoDAO.create(uid, lid, file, name, url, story);
}
```

I also have the `MultipartResolver` bean added to my config:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>
```

What could be causing the controller not to find the `file` request parameter? How else should I be reading the file to get it as a `MultipartFile`?

**Note: I am aware there are many other questions similar to mine in one way or another. None of the answers there helped me.**

---

the file is being sent as part of the payload. This is a how the payload looks like:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name" 
n 
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file" 
PNG [REMOVED FOR SPACE] % V4¡´ºÝÝ6nI6Ú"èdöîÎÉÎ83»ý¡OEP|1êÄ¿· (õÛ>´/ 
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY Content-Disposition: form-data; name="story" 
st 
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url" 
null 
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY--
```

Comment: are you sure photo.file is byte array??

Comment: Show the code for creating `photo.file` or console.log it to verify that it is a file. Use the Developer Console network tab to verify that a file has been sent as part of the payload.

Comment: @georgeawg yes the file is being sent as part of the payload. This is a how the payload looks like: `------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

n
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

PNG
[REMOVED FOR SPACE]
%
V4¡´ºÝÝ6nI6Ú"èdöîÎÉÎ83»ý¡OEP|1êÄ¿· (õÛ>´/

------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="story"

st
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url"

null
------WebKitFormBoundaryK0onA6CrI1KaKcJY--`

Comment: That file is not properly encoded in base64 which means `photo.file` is not a [File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File).